# Bootstrap Datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

1. How can i move calendar icon next by the date field?
2. Why the calendar is popped when page is loading? It is working fine in my local server but not sure what is the issue in JSFiddle.
3. Is there any way I can set the size of the date field as 10 so there will be no extra space in the input field?

   ```
   <div class ="form-group">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Received Date</label>       
     <div class="col-sm-2 input-append date" id="ARDT" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="ARDT" id="ARDT"  />
   <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```

   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aQGEF)

Comment: Remove `id="ARDT"` from the div that the datepicker is in. That should fix your issue where the calendar is showing when the page loads. You're initializing the datepicker using `id="ARDT"` and currently two elements have that `id`

Comment: That works.http://jsfiddle.net/aQGEF/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-2 input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="ARDT" 
        id="ARDT" maxlength="10" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

> - How can i move calendar icon next by the date field?

To move the calendar icon next to the date field, you can change the class of the div that the `input` and `span` are in from `input-append` to `input-group` and change the `span` class from `add-on` to `input-group-addon` as seen in the code above. There are a ton of different ways that this could be done though, this just seemed to be the quickest/easiest given how many classes each element already has.

> - Why the calendar is popped when page is loading?

You currently have a `div` and an `input` with the same `id` and I believe that's the issue. To fix your issue where the datepicker is showing when the page loads, remove `id="ARDT"` from the `div` that the `datepicker` is in.

> - Is there any way I can set the size of the date field as 10 so there will be no extra space in the input field?

Yes, that can be accomplished as easy as adding the `maxlength` attribute to the `input`.

Here is an updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmarsh123/tK4f6/2/) with those changes.

Comment: Is there any place where I can read and understand bootstratp CSS available classes and how they work ? How do you know there is "addon" is available tha tcan be combined with input-gtoup :) ?

Comment: See [**this link**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for the CSS section and [**this link**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) explains the `addon` class for Input Groups. IMO, the website lacks good documentation. I find myself using Google Chrome's Developer Tools, stepping through each section and looking at the CSS in great detail. I would also suggest taking a look at [**w3resource**](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php). It documents some aspects a little better, in my opinion that is.